# script works on wamp server but not on my vps

Tags: php, vps

Alright so I'm working on a forum project and I've ran into a snag. Uploading all my of files into wamp and starting the install process all goes fine. However when I upload the same files to my live website (using whm & cpanel) I go through the install process and when I get to index_3.php and type in all the server information I click continue and boom white screen, no errors. I checked my php.ini and turned display errors on and nothing. Checked the cpanel error log, nothing...

my index_3.php file:

```html
<?php if (!file_exists( "install.txt")){ die( "Installer locked."); } ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>forum Installer - Step 3 of 7</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/installer.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <img src="images/mbbinstall_logo.png" />
    <div id="container">
      <div id="menu">
        <a href="#" class="current">
          <img src="images/green/welcome.png" alt="Y">Welcome to forum!</a>
        <a href="#" class="current">
          <img src="images/green/percheck.png" alt="Y">Check Permissions</a>
        <a href="#" class="current">
          <img src="images/grey/mysql.png" alt="Y">Configure MySQL</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/grey/settings.png" alt="N">Configure Settings</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/grey/table.png" alt="N">Install Tables</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/grey/account.png" alt="N">Create Admin Account</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/grey/forum.png" alt="N">Your New Forum</a>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div class="title">forum MySQL Configuration</div>
        <div class="title2">Step 3 of 7</div>

        <?php if (isset($_GET[ "error"])){ echo "<div class=\"error\ ">Error accessing the MySQL database. Re-check database information. :[</div>"; } ?>

        <div class="box">
          <form action="index_4.php" method="post">
            Database Host
            <br />
            <span style="font-size:11px;">Commonly localhost, external MySQL servers may differ.</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="text" name="host" size="40" value="localhost">
            <br />
            <br />Database Username
            <br />
            <span style="font-size:11px;">The username you configured for your MySQL database.</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="text" name="user" size="40">
            <br />
            <br />Database Password
            <br />
            <span style="font-size:11px;">The password you configured for your MySQL database.</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="text" name="pass" size="40">
            <br />
            <br />Database Name
            <br />
            <span style="font-size:11px;">The name you configured for your MySQL database.</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="40">
            <br />
            <br />Password Key
            <br />
            <span style="font-size:11px;">A unique and random key to encrypt user passwords.</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="text" name="pass_key" size="40">
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Continue">
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div style="float:left;">
        minstaller v1.2 - Powered by: <a href='http://www.forum.net'>Bulletin Board</a>
      </div>
      <div style="float:right;">
        <a href="http://www.forum.net/docs" target="_blank" style="color:#808080;">I need help!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my index_4.php file that goes white after index_3.php:

```html
<?php if (!file_exists( "install.txt")){ die( "Installer locked."); } ?>
<?php # Database Connection if ($_POST[ "host"] !=n ull && $_POST[ "user"] !=n ull && $_POST[ "pass"] !=n ull && $_POST[ "name"] !=n ull && $_POST[ "pass_key"] !=n ull) { $mysqli=@ new mysqli($_POST[ "host"], $_POST[ "user"], $_POST[ "pass"], $_POST[
"name"]); } else { header( 'location: ./index_3.php?error=1'); exit(); } if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { header( 'location: ./index_3.php?error=1'); exit(); } else { $config_file='<?php
 /*******************
 |  forum software
 | powered by forum 1.2
 *******************/
 
 if(!defined("access")){ include("errors/access.html"); exit(); }
 
 /*******************
 | The following settings are related
 | to the MySQL side of the application
 *******************/
 
 $DB_NAME = "' . $_POST[ "name"] . '"; // Your database name
 $DB_HOST = "' . $_POST[ "host"] . '"; // Your database host
 $DB_USER = "' . $_POST[ "user"] . '"; // Your database username
 $DB_PASS = "' . $_POST[ "pass"] . '"; // Your database password
 
 // Please change the following key to a secure phrase - do not modify after board installation
 $config["password_key"] = "' . $_POST[ "pass_key"] . '";
?>
  '; $write_config=f open( "../forum/db_config.php", "w"); fwrite($write_config, $config_file); fclose($write_config); } ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>forum Installer - Step 3 of 7</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/installer.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <img src="images/mbbinstall_logo.png" />
    <div id="container">
      <div id="menu">
        <a href="#" class="current">
          <img src="images/green/welcome.png" alt="Y">Welcome to forum!</a>
        <a href="#" class="current">
          <img src="images/green/percheck.png" alt="Y">Check Permissions</a>
        <a href="#" class="current">
          <img src="images/grey/mysql.png" alt="Y">Configure MySQL</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/grey/settings.png" alt="N">Configure Settings</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/grey/table.png" alt="N">Install Tables</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/grey/account.png" alt="N">Create Admin Account</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/grey/forum.png" alt="N">Your New Forum</a>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div class="title">forum MySQL Configuration</div>
        <div class="title2">Step 3 of 7</div>

        <div class="box2">
          forum has successfully connected to your MySQL database. Next we are ready to configure your board settings! Click "Configure Settings" to begin your board configuration.
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;">
          <a href="index_5.php" class="button">Configure Settings</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div style="float:left;">
        forum installer v1.2 - Powered by: <a href='https://forum.net'>forum Bulletin Board</a>
      </div>
      <div style="float:right;">
        <a href="https://forum.net/docs.html" target="_blank" style="color:#808080;"> I need help!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show us the error report adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: `f open` => `fopen` ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how your code can work in your development environment. There is a PHP syntax error:

```
'; $write_config=f open( "../forum/db_config.php", "w"); fwrite($write_config, $config_file); fclose($write_config); } ?>
```

Must be

```
'; $write_config=fopen( "../forum/db_config.php", "w"); fwrite($write_config, $config_file); fclose($write_config); } ?>
```

(No space between "f" en "open")

Anyway: If you want to debug such an error make sure `error_reporting` has been set E_ALL. You may also want to check your server error-logs.

Comment: Actually that line of PHP looks like it is hanging there OUTSIDE of any php tags. The php tag is closed one line before

Comment: Oh right! And it is closed again at the end of the line. SOMETHING is wrong anyway :)

Comment: Alright I fixed the the space from f open to fopen. Now i get. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/forum/public_html/forum/install/index_4.php on line 15